# Change remote desktop wallpaper

Tags: powershell

I want to change the desktop wallpaper on a bunch of users desktop. I dont have AD so I can't use a Global Policy. I found a script that works locally. However, I dont know how to make this run remotely. I plan on running the script from my computer and having it apply on the remote desktop computers I have in a list.

```
set-itemproperty -path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -name WallPaper -value c:\wallpaper\wallpaper.jpg
```

How can I get this this script to run on remote computers?

Comment: Google for "psexec". Once you've found that the rest should be obvious. You might also use appropriate tags. 'powershell' has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: it's a powershell command.

Comment: What are the client operating systems?

Answer (score 2):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputerName { Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -name WallPaper -value c:\wallpaper\wallpaper.jpg }
```

However, this answer *does* assume that the remote machine has WinRM enabled (you don't mention any OS, even though Zoredache asked). Have a look at `Get-Help Invoke-Command` to see how to do credentials and impersonations if you're running outside of an AD environment.

Comment: The client operating systems are Windows XP and up.